# IF Exists then update in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

New to MySQL, need help in translating the next query to MySQL

```
If exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name= 'MyTable' and column_name = 'MyColumn') 
    begin 
            update MyTable set MyColumn='' where Code=21 
    end;
```

Comment: Why would you be attempting to update a column that might not exist?  I think you have a problem with your data model, and should fix the data model so this type of logic is unnecessary.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/169458/mysql-how-to-create-column-if-not-exists  this may give some pointers

Comment: Indeed. If you need to dynamically search a column you may have a very wide table of many columns of same type (i.e., years -2017,2018,2019, states -AL,AK,Az) that should be normalized (reshaped to long) into **one** column for values and **one** column for its indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments posted on your question, here is a code snippet that should answer your need. It works by first checking if the column exists in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, and then dynamically building a SQL query that is prepared, then executed. It the column does not exists, a dummy query is executed instead of the `UPDATE`. I tested it in [this db fiddlde](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4vqcbphHX79oTh7pgB9BnM/0).

```
SET @dbname = DATABASE();
SET @tablename = "my_table";
SET @columnname = "my_column";

-- check if the column exists
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    (table_name = @tablename)
    AND (table_schema = @dbname)
    AND (column_name = @columnname)
    ;

-- build a dynamic SQL statement
SET @preparedStatement = (SELECT IF(
  @cnt > 0,
  CONCAT("UPDATE ", @tablename, " SET ", @columnname, " = '' WHERE my_code = 21;"),
  "SELECT 1"
));

-- run the statement
PREPARE updateIfExists FROM @preparedStatement;
EXECUTE updateIfExists;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE updateIfExists;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought it would be less complicated and shorter but it still does the work.